# How can I modify context menu of Mathematica frontend?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, customization

I would like to add a new item to context menu. What I have to do?

I found this [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57089/how-to-customize-the-mathematicaclosingdialog-nb?rq=1), but it looks like the context menu does not create buy Mathematica resources.

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33833/34848) discussion helps?

Comment: Check [ContextMenu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ContextMenu) and [ComponentwiseContextMenu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ComponentwiseContextMenu).

Comment: @ercegovac @Kuba yes, thank you! But i still can not figure out how to apply newly constructed menu to all cells in my nb. What about it? I understand that i have to use `SetOptions`, but set option to _what_?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! Ok, I shell bear in mind.

Comment: If I can revive this thread. I copy Mathematica generated `Graphics[]` often and need it as Bitmap (would be even better if I could add an option to copy as JPG). When I right-click on the graphic (or several selected cells which I need to export as a Bitmap), it offers only the option to copy the selected Mathematica objects as a `Graphics[]` construct. I have to do it the long way - go into the Edit menu > Copy As > Bitmap. Can I edit the context menu to add this option or perhaps create a system-wide shortcut (something like Ctrl+Alt+C seeing as Ctrl+Shift+C)?